# C# - Data Source not appearing in binding source properties

Tags: c#, forms, bindingsource

Visual Studio is not adding new binding source (data source).

I added the new data source (a reference to a class I built) to the `Designer.cs` in the `InitializeComponent()` section.

Visual Studio recognized the data member but not the data source. Why won't it recognize my data source?

I added the following code to the end of the section:

```
this.CharterManagerbindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Program16.CharterManager);
```

I don't receive any errors in my code. It's like it doesn't even realize I entered it.

*** I am trying to add a binding source to a form so I can use the data source to auto populate information within the class it is linked to

Charter Manager Class Code

```
internal class CharterManager
    {
        #region "Instance Properties"
        public List<Charter> CharterList { get; private set; }

        #endregion


        #region "Constructor"
        public CharterManager()
        {
            CharterList = new List<Charter>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region "Methods"

        public void AddCharter(Charter aCharter)
        {
            CharterList.Add(aCharter);
        }

        public void AddCharter(string customerName, string yachtType, int yachtSize, decimal charterHours)
        {
            Charter aCharter = new Charter(customerName, yachtType, yachtSize, charterHours);

            CharterList.Add(aCharter);
        }

        public decimal FindLowestCharterFee()
        {
            decimal lowest = CharterList[0].CharterFee;

            foreach (Charter aCharter in CharterList)
            {
                if (aCharter.CharterFee < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = aCharter.CharterFee;
                }
            }

            return lowest;
        }

        public decimal GetAverageCharterFee()
        {
            return GetTotalCharterFee() / CharterList.Count;
        }

        public int GetCharterCount(int yachtSize)
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (Charter aCharter in CharterList)
            {
                if (aCharter.YachtSize == yachtSize)
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }

        public decimal GetTotalCharterFee()
        {
            decimal total = 0;

            foreach (Charter aCharter in CharterList)
            {
                total += aCharter.CharterFee;
            }

            return total;

CharterManagerGrid.Designer.CS Code

 private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.CharterManagerbindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.CharterManagerbindingSource)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // CharterManagerbindingSource
            // 
            this.CharterManagerbindingSource.DataMember = "Charter List";
            this.CharterManagerbindingSource.DataSource = new Program16.CharterManager();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 66);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 25;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // CharterManagerGrid
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "CharterManagerGrid";
            this.Text = "Charter Manager Grid";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.CharterManagerbindingSource)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource CharterManagerbindingSource;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
```

Comment: `typeof`?? wait, why is the `DataSource` not an `Enumerable`? what are you trying to do? what is this `CharterManager`?

Comment: It's for a course and that is what the prof used.

Comment: hi Ash, i think we need a wee-bit backtracking and see what your prof trying to do. what they want to provide on the `DataSource` and who used the source in question. it would be nice if you could pack the problem in an easy to read [mcve].

Comment: [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) for one accepts any `Object` as its `DataSource` and compiler wouldn't complain. However, it only recognizes certain objects mentioned under remarks. you can - arbitrarily - feed it with `string` and the compiler wouldn't complain. the control will silently do nothing.

Comment: "_I don't receive any errors in my code. It's like it doesn't even realize I entered it._" Wait, did you manually type `this.CharterManagerbindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Program16.CharterManager);` into the InitializeComponent() method of the CharterManagerGrid.Designer.cs file?

Comment: Yes I did.  Should It be elsewhere?

Comment: Well, look closely at the code comment directly above the InitializeComponent() declaration, and also note the name of the #region in which this method has been placed. If you notice that, you'll know why the code you added there doesn't stick... ;-)

Comment: Do you mind spelling it out for me? Also I added the Data Member to the same area and it linked it correctly to the binding source???